# Creation of New Thread is Giving an error

Tags: android

I am new to android i am trying to create a new thread to invoke another method.
But don't why it is throwing the error.

here is my stub

```
void test()

    {

        int i=0;
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Testing", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    }
    public void Button2_Click(View v)
    {
        Thread thread = new Thread()
        {
              @Override
              public void run() {
                  test();
              }
          };

        thread.start();
    }
```

Comment: You have declared it in an wrong way

Comment: Paste the log cat result

Comment: Make sure u r extending Thread class or implementing Runnable interface in your code... and then do this.. new Thread(yourClass.this)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't manipulate the UI from other threads than the main thread, and launching a Toast involves the user interface.

change your test function

```
    void test()

{

    int i=0;
    Log.d("Test","Testing");

}
```

now if the thread works you will se a log inside LogCat. If you want to display a Toast from another thread, you must use [Handler](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html) or [runOnUiThread](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#runOnUiThread%28java.lang.Runnable%29).

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by using [`Handler`](https://web.archive.org/web/20200810154212/http://www.tutorialforandroid.com/2009/01/using-handler-in-android.html).

Answer (score 0):

you can not put Toast inside a Thread. Remove your Toast message from your code. It will work fine.

Answer (score 0):

This is how you can do it.

```
`new Thread(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
      Bitmap b = loadImageFromNetwork();
      mImageView.setImageBitmap(b);
    }
  }).start();
'
```

Its a bracket mismatch.

Answer (score 0):

If you absolutely must Toast, you should use the runOnUIThread() method and pass it a new Runnable() anonymous class that Toasts in the run() method.

Irrelevantly, this doesn't seem to make a whole lot of sense. Perhaps you want to make test() static. Maybe post a better idea of what you'd like to do and exactly what error you're getting?